# initiate google re-marketing tag script with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to load Google remarking tag script on page with jquery. it appends the script correctly into the DOM but seems like it doesn't trigger that google script when page is loaded.

Following is the code i have tried so far.

```
var google = google || {};

google.remarketingtag = new function () {
this.init = function () {
    var RemarketingTag = "";

    RemarketingTag = '<script type="text/javascript">' +
                     '/* <![CDATA[ */ \n' +
                     'var google_conversion_id = 396654566;\n' +
                     'var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;\n' +
                     'var google_remarketing_only = true;\n' +
                     '/* ]]> */' +
                     '</script>';
    RemarketingTag += '<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>';
    RemarketingTag += '<noscript> \n' +
                      '<div style="display:inline;"> \n' +
                      '<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/995380491/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/> \n' +
                      '</div> \n' +
                      '</noscript>';



$("body").append(RemarketingTag);
    $.getScript("//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js");

}
}
```

when I insert google re-marketing script directly on page it works perfectly.

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any one who can help with this issue?